# Extension is not saving data to MySQL

Tags: php

I am developing an custom extension for Magento 1.9.0.1 and here is what i have done so far:

Here is my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <VivasIndustries_Vshippingone>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </VivasIndustries_Vshippingone>
    </modules>

    <global> 
         <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote>                           
                <my_custom_input_field_one><to_order>*</to_order></my_custom_input_field_one>
                <my_custom_input_field_two><to_order>*</to_order></my_custom_input_field_two>
            </sales_convert_quote>

            <sales_convert_order>                                              
                <my_custom_input_field_one><to_quote>*</to_quote></my_custom_input_field_one>
                <my_custom_input_field_two><to_quote>*</to_quote></my_custom_input_field_two>
            </sales_convert_order>
        </fieldsets>
        <helpers>
            <vshippingone>
                <class>VivasIndustries_Vshippingone_Helper</class>
            </vshippingone>            
        </helpers>

        <models>
            <vshippingone>
                <class>VivasIndustries_Vshippingone_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>vshippingone_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </vshippingone>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <vshippingone_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>VivasIndustries_Vshippingone</module>
                    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </vshippingone_setup>
            <vshippingone_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </vshippingone_write>
            <vshippingone_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </vshippingone_read>
        </resources>

    <events>
        <checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
             <observers>
                 <vshippingone>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>vshippingone/observer</class>
                      <method>saveCustomData</method>
                 </vshippingone>
             </observers>
        </checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>         
    </events>
        <blocks>
            <vshippingone>
                <class>VivasIndustries_Vshippingone_Block</class>
            </vshippingone>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Here is my Observer:

```
<?PHP
class VivasIndustries_Vshippingone_Model_Observer 
{
    public function saveCustomData($event)
    {
        $quote = $event->getQuote();
        $quote->setData('my_custom_input_field_one', 'Sample data 1');
        $quote->setData('my_custom_input_field_two', 'Sample data 2');
        return $this;
    } 
}
```

Here is my SQL installer:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("order", "my_custom_input_field_one", array("type"=>"text"));
$installer->addAttribute("quote", "my_custom_input_field_one", array("type"=>"text"));
$installer->endSetup();
```

Note that `my_custom_input_field_one` was created via the extension SQL installer file. `my_custom_input_field_two` i created with PHPMyAdmin with the exactly the same structure and settings like `my_custom_input_field_one`.

When i submit an order, the data for `my_custom_input_field_one` is inserted. So `Sample data 1` is there. However nothing is inserted in `my_custom_input_field_two` which i find strange and that is my problem.

Can you give me any advice ? How can i fix this problem ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If both are the same in terms of coding, the only thing i can think of is maybee to "Flush cache storage" on the cache page. I also had same sort of problem, it seems that cache storage stores model/database data.

Comment: This should be `$installer->addAttribute("quote", "my_custom_input_field_one", array("type"=>"text"));` changed to `$installer->addAttribute("quote", "my_custom_input_field_two", array("type"=>"text"));` I believe.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in those lines, the first attribute is linked to the order, and the second is linked to the quote, see the first parameter of addAttribute:

```
$installer->addAttribute("order", "my_custom_input_field_one", array("type"=>"text"));
$installer->addAttribute("quote", "my_custom_input_field_one", array("type"=>"text"));
```

EDIT: my bad, those two are related to the first attribute. Do you have the same code for the second attribute ?

EDIT 2: so if that's all you have in your installer then you should also have the following lines for the second attributes

```
$installer->addAttribute("order", "my_custom_input_field_two", array("type"=>"text"));
$installer->addAttribute("quote", "my_custom_input_field_two", array("type"=>"text"));
```

Comment: No thats all what i have in the installer

Comment: See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache even if cache is disable and try again as database cache might cause issues.

Comment: I have tried this. It is not helping